# Create CloudFront distribution that accepts only signed URL’s with serverless

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, serverless

I want to create a web cloudFront distribution that can be accessed only using signed URL's.

On creating the distribution manually, there is an option Restrict Viewer Access under the Default Cache Behavior Settings.

[image]

I want to create the distribution using the serverless framework but I can't find the CloudFormation attribute for the Restrict Viewer Access property.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The documentation is totally not clear on this one. If the signing keys are in the same account you are deploying the CloudFront Distribution to you just need:

```
    TrustedSigners:
      - self
```

Note sometime in late 2020 CloudFront provided a way to create signing keys that does not involve using the AWS account root user. See these docs for more information. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-trusted-signers.html#choosing-key-groups-or-AWS-accounts

Answer (score 3):

Little late on this. Adding to the above answer.

There are two ways to do it through CloudFromation.

1. TrustedKeyGroups - A list of key groups that CloudFront can use to validate signed URLs or signed cookies.
2. TrustedSigners - A list of AWS account IDs whose public keys CloudFront can use to validate signed URLs or signed cookies.

**When a cache behavior contains TrustedSigners or TrustedKeyGroups property, CloudFront requires signed URLs or signed cookies for all requests that match the cache behavior.** This is already assumed by CloudFront through these settings so you don't need to specify any other property(Restrict viewer access on UI).

As per AWS, They recommend using **TrustedKeyGroups** instead of TrustedSigners.

AWS URL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-cachebehavior.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-cachebehavior-trustedsigners